# Mancha azul em interação com video

Tags: flash

Estou com um baita problema. Tenho uma aplicação em flash que captura imagens e o nome do usuário que esta logado em nosso site.

Nós exibimos um vídeo e sobrepomos essas informações (imagem e nome) sobre o vídeo.

A interação está funcionando normalmente e perfeitamente, as imagens são capturadas e o nome do usuário também, só que, na hora de exibir a imagem ou nome sobre o vídeo, a interação fica com umas manchas azuladas.

Alguem já passou por isso e sobreviveu?

[image: printscreen]

Comment: Ao que parece é um problema de resolução. Você está carregando o vídeo com qual objeto? `FLVPlayback`, `VideoPlayer` com `Stream`? A cor em azul é a mesma cor do fundo do palco? A propriedade `stage.scaleMode` está definida como o que? Você alterou `width` e `height` do objeto de vídeo antes de adicioná-lo ao palco?

Comment: Fala Walace, obg pelo seu contato, então man, eu consegui resolver o problema, mais foi uma série de passos que precisei dar.

Comment: Estou documentando tudo e vou postar a solução para a galera com os print´s e tals!

Comment: Tudo bem @FernandoPimenta, mas note que eu não sou o Wallace! Meu nick aparece no final do [comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86572/mancha-azul-em-intera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-video#comment174744_86572)!

Comment: Rss desculpe Biio, então foi o seguinte, foi mais simples que eu imaginava, depois de varias tentativas eu consegui minimizar o problema, mais mesmo assim não ficava arrumado a mancha persistia em aparecer. A solução foi atualizar o flash player para a ultima versão disponivel.